# Query to all contents of tabel in related model in laravel

Tags: laravel

Assume we have a model name "Article" in Laravel and want to make query for retrieving latest articles, so one way is to define a method in the "Article" model like this:

```
public function newArticle()
{
    return  static::where('created_at', '>', Carbon::subMonths(1));
}
```

The question is, why we should use

> static::

in the above code?

Is it possible to use

> $this  or   self::

instead of

"static::" ?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could but there is not interest because:

- `where` method does not exist statically on `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model` class, so it calls `__callStatic` magic method which delegates the call to an instance

```php
/**
     * Handle dynamic static method calls into the method.
     *
     * @param  string  $method
     * @param  array  $parameters
     * @return mixed
     */
    public static function __callStatic($method, $parameters)
    {
        return (new static)->$method(...$parameters);
    }
```

- It calls `where` method on instance but it does not exist either, so it calls `__call` magic method which delegates it an `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder` instance.

```php
/**
     * Handle dynamic method calls into the model.
     *
     * @param  string  $method
     * @param  array  $parameters
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function __call($method, $parameters)
    {
        if (in_array($method, ['increment', 'decrement'])) {
            return $this->$method(...$parameters);
        }

        return $this->forwardCallTo($this->newQuery(), $method, $parameters);
    }
```

```php
/**
     * Get a new query builder for the model's table.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder
     */
    public function newQuery()
    {
        return $this->registerGlobalScopes($this->newQueryWithoutScopes());
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.